# Circumference length of an ellipse

Tags: definite-integrals, conic-sections

I tried to find out the circumference of an ellipse many times by using integration but got stuck in the middle. So I tried to search on Google. Some sites said that it is bit difficult to find the circumference of ellipse and gave me some approximations which produce almost accurate results. But none of them gave me the original formula. Is there any such formula where I can just put the values of minor and major axis to get its accurate circumference?

Comment: See here: http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/250a/ellipse-length.pdf

Comment: First one is an approxition while the second one gives an infinite series(where I actually got stuck). Is there any finite formula to do this???

Comment: Unfortunately, no... But the second paper gives a formula that approximates the result to a very high degree. Just calculate the first three to four terms.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot... that was a great help.

Comment: However there are some which approximate to a high level of accuracy: https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/ellipse-perimeter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circumference of the ellipse (or the length of an arc of ellipse) can't be expressed with the *elementary functions*: it depends on the *elliptic integral of the second kind*:
$$E(k)=\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2t\mathstrut}\,\mathrm dt. $$
If the ellipse has semi-major and semi-minor axes $a$ and $b$ respectively, the circumference is equal to
$$4aE(e),\qquad \text{ where }\enspace e=\sqrt{1-\dfrac{b^2}{a^2}}\enspace\text{(eccentricity)}.$$
You only can have  an expansion as a power series for the function $E(k)$:
$$E(k)=\frac\pi2\biggl(1-\Bigl(\frac 12\Bigr)^{\!2}\frac{k^2}1 -\Bigl(\frac {1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\Bigr)^{\!2}\frac{k^4}3-\Bigl(\frac {1\cdot 3\cdot5}{2\cdot 4\cdot6}\Bigr)^{\!2}\frac{k^6}5-\dotsm$$