# Get circumference of an ellipse

Tags: geometry

How can I measure the circumference of an ellipse, just by knowing only the width and the height. I would like a nice easy solution. If there is any complex trigonometry, etc., please explain what they do.

[image: Ellipse]

Thanks.

Comment: [Elliptic Integrals.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference)

Comment: The WikiPedia article of the Ellipse expleins it quite well ..., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference

Comment: As the other comments say, you're out of luck. The circumference is hard - but the area is easy. its just $\pi/4 \times$ width $\times$ height,

Comment: Can you please explain all of the trigonometry and the meaning.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Not at all. The linked question deals with approximations *not* with the measurement of the circumference itself.

Comment: @mrtaurho How about https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584033/circumference-length-of-an-ellipse

Comment: @YuiToCheng Better^^